# CSS - Absolutely positioned divs are not sticking to right edge when "right:0px" in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-position, html

I found an example [here](http://www.kyleschaeffer.com/tutorials/karate-corners-easy-rounded-corners-xhtml-no-script/) of using rounded corners using a single image. I've got this working perfectly in IE7+ and FireFox.

The following is an example tab layout:

```
<div class="tab"><div class="corner TL"></div><div class="corner TR"></div>
    <div class="inner"><p>Test 1</p></div>
</div>
<div class="tab"><div class="corner TL"></div><div class="corner TR"></div>
    <div class="inner"><p>Test - 2</p></div>
</div>
<div class="tab"><div class="corner TL"></div><div class="corner TR"></div>
    <div class="inner"><p>Test - 3</p></div>
</div>
```

The following is my CSS Style:

```
.corner
{
        background:url(../Images/LightCorner.gif);
        position:absolute;
        width:13px;
        height:13px;
        overflow:hidden;    
}

.inner
{
        position:relative;
        padding:13px;
        margin:0px;
}

.inner p
{
        padding:0px;
}

.tab
{
        color:#FFF;
        float:left;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-right:5px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
}

.tab p
{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
}

.tab
{
        background:#B5B5B5;
}


.TL
{
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        background-position:0px 0px;
}
.TR
{
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        background-position:-13px 0px;
}

.TL, .TR
{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        position:absolute;
}
```

The issue is that when my div's width is an **even** number, I end up with a 1px right-hand border, as though the top right div is actually being positioned as right:1px. When the width is an **odd** number I do not see the right hand grey colour of the tab and the div is displayed as expected.

The image I am using can be found [here](http://generictypetea.co.uk/Images/LightCorner.gif). A full example can be found [here](http://generictypetea.co.uk/HTMLPage1.htm).

Why is the top right div not being positioned correctly at right:0px? Why do I end up with a 1px gap in IE6 when the tab width is an even number?

Comment: Have you tried removing all the line breaks so that the whole thing is a single line?

Comment: No, and why would that achieve anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is that when my div's width
>   is an even number, I end up with a 1px
>   right-hand border, as though the top
>   right div is actually being positioned
>   as right:1px. When the width is an odd
>   number I do not see the right hand
>   grey colour of the tab and the div is
>   displayed as expected.

There is nothing with your code, it is a bug in Internet Explorer 6. When absolute-positioning things to the right or to the bottom, the actual position will be rounded to 2px, giving 1px "margin" when the total width/height is even (or odd). Unfortunately, you need JavaScript to fix that.

You can check [this example](http://denilsonsa.selfip.org/~denilson/css/position_absolute.html) (written by me) and slowly resize the IE6 window, pixel-by-pixel. You will notice that the position of bottom and right boxes will be updated only once every two pixels. Another guy has also found and documented this bug on [his site](http://marc.baffl.co.uk/bugs.php#ab-pos).

I've already written one to fix height-calculation when positioning top and bottom, and leaving height as auto. I use [this script](http://www.vialink.com.br/js/iefixes.js) on [this site](http://www.vialink.com.br/). In your cause, this script can be modified to calculate the left-offset based on `available_width-(right+width)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

body {
 margin: 0;
}

Comment: Yes, doesn't fix it. The issue appears to me that right is set to 0px, but it's getting rendered to 1px for some unknown reason!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
right:-1px;
```

for IE6

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but that reverses the issue! I.e. the divs with even widths are now OK and the divs with odd widths now have the pesky gap.